# Mathematics for machine learning

Tags: mathematics-education, machine-learning

I would like to know what mathematics topics are the most important to learn before actually studying the theory on neural networks.

I ask that because I will start to learn about neural networks and machine learning on my own to help in the analysis I am doing on my PhD about patterns of genome evolution.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Marcos, machine learning is still very young, and in a state of great flux.  What this means is that the techniques used are constantly developing, and if you looked across the whole spectrum, you'd see a dizzying variety of methods.  What I recommend is to google around for courses on topics you are interested in, both at the school you will attend and at others you respect, and see what the textbooks, notes, and homework assignments look like.

Comment: Mathematical Logic is the most basic subject you need to  learn.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For basic neural networks (i.e. if you just need to build and train one), I think basic calculus is sufficient, maybe things like gradient descent and more advanced optimization algorithms. For more advanced topics in NNs (convergence analysis, links between NNs and SVMs, etc.), somewhat more advanced calculus may be needed.

For machine learning, mostly you need to know probability/statistics, things like Bayes theorem, etc.

Since you are a biologist, I don't know whether you studied linear algebra. Some basic ideas from there are definitely extremely useful. Specifically, linear transformations, diagonalization, SVD (that's related to PCA, which is a pretty basic method for dimensionality reduction).

The book by Duda/Hart/Stork has several appendices which describe the basic math needed to understand the rest of the book.

Answer (score 12):

I think the answer depends on which structure you are looking to approximate, and, in what sense you want to approximate it.  Below, you'll find a few contemporary references to help out :)

---

**Shallow Feedforward Networks and Deep Convolutional Networks**

I would suggest some [Harmonic/Fourier analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_analysis), some [constructive approximation theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructive_Approximation), and their intersection [(esp.: Besov Spaces)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Besov_space).  This is because, many of the quantitative approximation theorems for shallow (1-hidden layer) feedforward networks are derived via such methods.  Relevant (contemporary) papers for such methods include:

- [Approximation spaces of deep neural networks - Gribonval et al. 2021](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00365-021-09543-4)
- [Approximation rates for neural networks with general activation functions - Siegel and Xu, 2021](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0893608020301891#!)
- [Adaptivity of deep ReLU network for learning in Besov and mixed smooth Besov spaces: optimal rate and curse of dimensionality - Taiji Suzuki](https://openreview.net/forum?id=H1ebTsActm)
  This particular point carries over equally to (deep) convolutional networks:
- [Universality of deep convolutional neural networks - Ding-Xuan Zhou 2020](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1063520318302045)

---

**Deep Feedforward Networks and Optimal Rates**

Otherwise, for deep feed-forward networks some of the more insightful approximation-theoretic results rely on [Vapnik-Chervonekis Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vapnik%E2%80%93Chervonenkis_theory).  These are then typically used to derive "optimal approximation rates"; see especially these papers:

- [Optimal approximation of continuous functions by very deep ReLU networks D. Yarotsky 2018](http://proceedings.mlr.press/v75/yarotsky18a)
- [The phase diagram of approximation rates for deep neural networks - Dmitry Yarotsky, Anton Zhevnerchuk - 2020](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/2020/hash/979a3f14bae523dc5101c52120c535e9-Abstract.html)

---

**Non-Euclidean Input/Output Spaces and Topological Embeddings**

These results typically rely on results of a more topological flavor.  I would [Von Mill's book](http://%20The%20Infinite-Dimensional%20Topology%20of%20Function%20Spaces) and of course basic general topology textbooks [like Munkres' classic](https://www.pearson.com/us/higher-education/product/Munkres-Topology-2nd-Edition/9780131816299.html).  The only  universal approximation theorems I know of in this context are:

- [Non-Euclidean Universal Approximation, 2020](https://proceedings.neurips.cc/paper/2020/file/786ab8c4d7ee758f80d57e65582e609d-Paper.pdf)
- [NEU: A Meta-Algorithm for Universal UAP-Invariant Feature Representation, 2021](https://www.jmlr.org/papers/v22/18-803.html)

---

**Recurrent Structures and Reservoir Computers**

If you're looking for something a bit more "dynamic" in nature, then I would recommend brushing up on your functional analysis, measure theory, and sequences in Banach spaces.  The first of these papers makes extensive use of ideas surrounding [Rademacher Complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rademacher_complexity) and there are deep connections to the [theory of dynamical systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamical_systems_theory).

- [Risk Bounds for Reservoir Computing - Gonon, Grigoryeva, Ortega - 2020](https://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume21/19-902/19-902.pdf)
- [Differentiable reservoir computing - Grigoryeva, Ortega - 2019](https://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume20/19-150/19-150.pdf)

I mention here also the developing connections between learning dynamics and [rough path theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rough_path).  See:

- [Deep signature transforms - Kidger, Bonnier, Perez Arribas, Salvi, Lyons - 2019](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/2019/hash/d2cdf047a6674cef251d56544a3cf029-Abstract.html)
- [Discrete-Time Signatures and Randomness in Reservoir Computing - Cuchiero, Gonon, Grigoryeva, Ortega, Teichmann - 2021](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/9442205)

---

**Qualitative Approximation by Shallow Feedforward Networks "Classical Style"**

Let me mention that, classical *(qualitative)* universal approximation results are based on the [Stone-Weierstraß theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem) from [approximation theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximation_theory).  Some results rely on the theory of [LF-Spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LF-space) which are a class of [Locally-Convex spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locally_convex_topological_vector_space) with a particularly ["category-theoretic$\cap$functional-analytic flavor"](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/83363/is-there-a-nice-application-of-category-theory-to-functional-complex-harmonic-an).  For modern formulations of the result in rather general contexts, see:

- [Stone–Weierstraß and extension theorems in the nonlocally
  convex case - Timofte, Timofte, Khan - 2018](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022247X18301823)
- [Stone-weierstraß theorems for group-valued functions - Galindo, Sanchis, 2004](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02772227)

The last of these references needs only a bit of background in [topological groups](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/topological+group).

---

**Memory Capacity/ Interpolation Capabilities**
These results have a variety of backgrounds.  The latter of these results draws from the [Chow-Rashevskii Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chow%E2%80%93Rashevskii_theorem) and [control theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_theory).

- [Small ReLu networks are powerful memorizers:  A tight analysis ofmemorization capacity - Yun, Sra, Jadbabaie - 2019](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/2019/hash/dbea3d0e2a17c170c412c74273778159-Abstract.html)
- [Memory Capacity of Neural Networks with Threshold and Rectified Linear Unit Activations -  Vershynin - 2020](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/pdf/10.1137/20M1314884)
- [Deep Neural Networks, Generic Universal Interpolation, and Controlled ODEs - Cuchiero, Larsson, Teichmann - 2020](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/19M1284117)

---

**Impossibility Theorems**
Let me briefly round off this post with the following interesting results.  The pre-requisits for these papers are a typical background; nonetheless, their results are fascinating.

- [Minimum Width for Universal Approximation - Park, Yun, Lee, Shin - 2021](https://openreview.net/forum?id=O-XJwyoIF-k)
- [Deep, Skinny neural networks are not universal approximators - Johnson - 2018](https://openreview.net/forum?id=ryGgSsAcFQ)

Comment: These references look good for many people on this site, but probably not for someone like the OP doing a PhD about patterns of genome evolution.

Comment: Fair enough, but the thread can still be useful to some other readers (or if the OP needs some more technical details or estimates).

Answer (score 6):

I believe [Ian Goodfellow and Yoshua Bengio's Deep Learning](https://www.amazon.ca/Deep-Learning-Ian-Goodfellow/dp/0262035618/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1510605367&sr=8-1&keywords=Deep%20Learning) book covers the basics and also how you would use it for research. The chapters are also [available online for free](http://www.deeplearningbook.org/).

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at the web page for Michael Steele's course [Probability Inequalities and Machine Learning](http://www-stat.wharton.upenn.edu/~steele/Courses/9xx/index.html), and the various texts linked to there.

Comment: That page seems to be more related to what's called "learning theory", i.e. theoretical (mathematical) analysis of various learning algorithms, their performance bounds (hence probability inequalities), etc.

Comment: Just a comment. Imo learning theory is more statistics than mathematics.  For example, the approximation theory of various learning models isn't learning theory while it's applied analysis.

Answer (score 4):

As a deep learning practitioner with mathematical background I was yearning to have some satisfying mathematical framework of what I do in my every day job. In my opinion, very well fitted mathematical foundations of deep learning principles are captured simply by [Empirical risk minimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empirical_risk_minimization) (ERM) concept. I encourage everyone to read just Chapter 1 from [The Nature of Statistical Learning Theory](https://statisticalsupportandresearch.files.wordpress.com/2017/05/vladimir-vapnik-the-nature-of-statistical-learning-springer-2010.pdf) of V. Vapnik. In my opinion it is an eye opener.

Answer (score 0):

I recently [wrote an answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/467056/11540) to a related question, about math research that can enhance machine learning. But, part of what I wrote is also related to a learning resource that might help someone interested in neural networks. That resource is the book [Data Science for Mathematicians](https://www.routledge.com/Data-Science-for-Mathematicians/Carter/p/book/9780367027056), edited by Nathan Carter. It assumes the audience is a mathematician (at, say, the graduate student level), then gives high level treatments of:

- programming with data,
- linear algebra (and its applications to data analytics),
- basic statistics,
- clustering,
- operations research,
- dimensionality reduction,
- machine learning,
- deep learning, and
- topological data analysis

I should disclose that I wrote one of the chapters, but don't have any financial stake in the book. I recommend it because I think it's great, and will help mathematicians who want to embrace data science in their research, teaching, or as an alternative career. I hope it helps!